# Xcode Application drag or move label

Tags: ios, uilabel, drag

I want to drag my label in Application. I create new label when starting Application

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];

myLabel.text = @"DRAG ME!!!";

[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

How can I drag this label? I can't find normal tutorial and i new in Xcode...

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation may help you. Change your above label with this one and you can see that now your label is draggable.

```
#import "DraggableLabel.h"

@interface DraggableLabel()
{
     CGPoint _previousLocation;
}

@end

@implementation DraggableLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        self.gestureRecognizers = @[panRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    _previousLocation = self.center;
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer
{
     CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.superview];
     self.center = CGPointMake(_previousLocation.x + translation.x,
                          _previousLocation.y + translation.y);
}

@end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the view controller's responsibility to position the view in response to drags? Seems like a leaky abstraction to have the view reposition itself. At least provide a delegate protocol that the VC can implement to reposition the view in response to drags.

Comment: Agreed, Implementing delegate will do the job.